# in a paragraph how to find the each line's first and last word programmatically in android textview

Tags: android, textview

I want to  find the line's first and last word of a paragraph.

sample :

**My** country is Turkey.I love my country very **much**.

**There** are four season in my country in a year. **Each**

**one** has 3 month. That's the place where every **one**

**live** **in**.

In such a paragraph, I want the words that is in Bold.This paragraph is in textview
and the code must take care of the width of textview.If width changes, first and last words also changes, and algorithm must find them.

If you help, I'll be glad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how android handles the actual placement of text with resizes and all that. I really doubt that it adds in tab carriages and newlines to the text to display them, but if it does, you could use regex to find that. Or regex with the line anchors. Take a look at this, see if it helps:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html